# Catching exception from custom sqrt function fails in C++

Tags: c++, exception, g++4.8

I was trying to demonstrate exception handling and came across an oddity I can't solve.  The problem arises in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

double sqrt(double x) {                                                         
    if ( x < 0 ){
        throw invalid_argument("sqrt received negative argument");
    }
    return sqrt(x);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    try {
        double s = sqrt(-1);
    }
    catch (const exception& e) {
        cout << "Caught " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code fails:

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
 what():  sqrt received negative argument
 ./dostuff.sh: line 8:  3472 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./may_22.exe
```

If, however, I either change the name of the sqrt function I write to "mySqrt", or remove the  header, the exception is properly caught.  Any idea what is causing this?

I'm compiling via

```
 g++ -g -Wall -std=c++0x -Weffc++   may_22.cpp -o may_22.exe
```

with `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1`

**EDIT**: To clarify, this does not seem like a namespace issue. The code is clearly calling my sqrt function, as shown by the exception message.

EDIT 2: This code still fails to handle the exception for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>

double sqrt(double x) {
    if ( x < 0 ){
        throw std::invalid_argument("sqrt received negative argument");
    }
    return std::sqrt(x);                                                        
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    try {
        double s = sqrt(-1);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it's a duplicate. Even if it's in `std` I don't understand why exception is thrown and not caught

Comment: Assuming the name isn't a problem, if you didn't throw an exception wouldn't the function be infinitely recursive?  Your code generates a linker error on Visual Studio but works fine there and [here](http://ideone.com/uziiN9) if the function name is changed.

Comment: Well, technically the link is correct: this is evidently causing undefined behavior, so the compiler is free to do as it pleases (such as fail to catch an exception properly).

Comment: I think the question should be unlocked as there is information here. Sqrt exists in the global namespace as part of the c libraries. Is it possible that std::sqrt is implemented in terms of ::sqrt on your system?

Comment: [g++ does reject your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90fb31b221985a15)

Answer (score 2):

You just can't call a function `sqrt`, since that's reserved. Your function is getting called, but your implementation is also including a header file that says that `sqrt` cannot throw. Change the name of the function to something else and the problem will go away.

You can also see the problem if you change your function to `double sqrt(double const& x) {`. You'll probably get an error about conflicting overloads.

Answer (score 0):

sqrt() is reserved from the cmath library.
Try changing it to double squareRoot(double x).
That should at least fix that problem.
Sorry, that's all I can help you with.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).